# Why we usually dont use strong parameters for http GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, http

I've seen strong parameters used for write HTTP verbs,

for example in rails

```
User.new( params.require(:user).permit(:name) )
```

but usually you wont see this kind of param whitelisting for HTTTP GET, why? i imagine it must be because of writes are more sensitive, but can't think of specific explanation.

Comment: I think it's indeed because writes are more sensitive. Also, in your question you're describing the NEW action; even if it was tampered with, you will have param whitelisting in the CREATE / UPDATE actions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strong parameters were added to make sure that no model attributes would be updated which you did not specifically allow. If a user is able to change his/her website URL, you probably don't want him/her to change the role_id attribute, which would be trivial if you did not sanitize the input.

GET requests are typically not used to create or update models.

Comment: Thx so I suppose this only helps in the case we want to directly use the params map passed in, rather than handle each property  separately .as the latter will ignore the unwanted params